# define nested design in R

Tags: r, statistics, mixed-models, nlme

I have three factors A,B,C. B and C are random. And B is nested with A. There is interacion between C and B , C and A. I try with `lme` function, but I don't know how to define nesting and the interacion C and B.

```
lme(dades~A*C,random=list(~1|B, ~1|C),data=mydata)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to try my best to help here, but if someone else has a better answer, of course please follow their advice.

First, start by building your unconditional model - a model without any predictor or independent variables. In your case, it looks like A represents the level 2 groups. Here would be the unconditional model using the nlme package you appear to be using:

```
model1 <- lme(fixed = dades~1, random =~1|A)
```

Then, you can model the effects of B and C (allowing the intercepts but not the slopes of B and C to be random at level 2):

```
model2 <- lme(fixed = dades~B+C, random =~1|A)
```

You can allow the slopes to be random across A:

```
model3 <- lme(fixed = dades~B+C, random = ~B+C|A)
```

To model the interactions, you can multiply the predictors (as you did):

```
model4 <- lme(fixed = dades~B+C+B*C, random = ~1|A)
```

I'm not sure how you can add an interaction between C and A, since A is not a predictor variable, but is the level 2 groups.

Again, if another answer is more helpful, please use that.

Also, I recommend this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Multilevel-Modeling-Statistics-Behavioral-Sciences/dp/1466515856/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1418597075&sr=8-1&keywords=multilevel+modeling+r](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1466515856)